# Identify which script sets a cookie

Tags: cookies

I need to create a list of cookies and their sources. Is there any way to understand from which script particular cookie comes from? For example, '_ga' cookie is definitely set by some of the google analytics script, but is it possible to identify which script exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some of the cookies are set by ajax-responses (you can find such cookies in Chrome Dev Tools -> Network tab and make a search with string 'set-cookie:').

As for the rest, I took a code snippet from here [Breaking JavaScript execution always when cookie is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245885/breaking-javascript-execution-always-when-cookie-is-set)
but instead of debugging I'm calling console.trace() function, which actually shows functions and their sources. That's it!