# Is it possible to set breakpoint in devtools when cookie is set?

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome-devtools, devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I'd like to set breakpoint when cookie is being set, either by HTTP response header `Set-Cookie` or by javascript `document.cookie='cookie1=value1`.
I need this because when I go to some websites they have huge amount of requests and it's hard to find which one of those sets the cookie I'd like to inspect. Also, if cookie is set via JS I'd also like to breakpoint on that and inspect/debug code around it.

Is this possible to do in Chrome, FireFox or any other browser?

Comment: Related question: [Breaking JavaScript execution always when cookie is set - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245885/breaking-javascript-execution-always-when-cookie-is-set).

Answer (score 1):

The question asks for two ways how cookies can be set. So this requires two separate approaches.

## Set via JavaScript

Firebug had that feature back then, though to my knowledge none of the current developer tools have that feature.

For Chrome, I created a [feature request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1171347) to add that some time ago. And for Firefox there is also a [feature request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=895893).

### Workaround

Until the browser vendors implement that feature you can use a workaround by manually setting the breakpoint(s). To do that you have to search for "document.cookie" within all JavaScript sources and set (conditional) breakpoints where the property gets assigned a new value.

#### In Chrome

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the Search panel.
2. Enable the button to search for regular expressions.
3. Type `document\.cookie\s*=` into the search field and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Double-click the first match
5. a) Set a breakpoint on the matched line (you might need to pretty-print the script first)
   b) To only stop when a specific cookie is set, right-click the line bar, choose *Add conditional breakpoint...* from the context menu and enter `cookiename === 'x'`, where `cookiename` is the name of the variable that holds the cookie name and `'x'` is the name of the cookie you want to stop at.
6. Repeat steps 4 and 5 for the rest of the matches

#### In Firefox

1. Switch to the Debugger panel
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the search field.
3. Type `document.cookie` into the search field and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Double-click the first match where it's being set.
5. a) Set a breakpoint on the matched line (you might need to pretty-print the script first)
   b) To only stop when a specific cookie is set, right-click the line bar, choose *Add condition* from the context menu and enter `cookiename === 'x'`, where `cookiename` is the name of the variable that holds the cookie name and `'x'` is the name of the cookie you want to stop at.
6. Repeat steps 4 and 5 for the rest of the matches where `document.cookie` is being set.

## Set via `Set-Cookie` header

As the `Set-Cookie` header is part of a network request, the best place to look for it is the *Network* panel.

The headers are not directly shown in the list of requests. Though there is a way to search for them in the browsers. As both Chrome and Firefox offer a very similar UI, here are the steps for both:

1. Switch to the *Network* panel.
2. Reload the page.
3. Click the magnifier glass icon in the panel's toolbar to open the search sidebar.
4. Enter the name of the cookie and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Go through the list of matches and check where the `Set-Cookie` header is listed.

---

The actual question here is obviously "Where does a specific cookie come from?".

To get a centralized answer to that question, I [created a feature request for Firefox to add the origin information of cookies to the Storage Inspector](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1350812) some time ago.

Comment: Will the workarounds in the answer catch cookies set by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie?

Comment: I realized that the original question also asked for that and that my answer ignored that. So I added this information now. Note that cookies set in JavaScript and cookies set via network requests currently require different handling to find their origin.
Please also see my last note in the answer regarding a feature request for a centralized way to get the origin of a cookie!